# Window 8.1 - Cant select "Disable driver signature enforcement" on Startup Settings screen

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers

I've a Toshiba notebook with Windows 8.1 and I need to install a driver for a hardware but the driver has no signature. I restarted windows as described in so many articles and got the screen below. But I cant select the 7th option, I tried "F7", "7" on both sides of the keyboard, plugging 2 different USB keyboards but no luck. So far only power key is working at this screen. It turns off the computer and it boots normally when I start it again.

[image]

Comment: So you can't type 1-9 at all?  Done F10 work?  How about Enter?

Comment: I tried all the options 1-9, f10, enter.. nothing happened. only power key worked

Comment: What do you mean by "power key"?  The power button on the computer?  Or does your keyboard actually have a power key on it?  Does any of the keyboards work in the BIOS?

Comment: sorry for confusion, it is the power button on the computer.. keyword works until coming to that screen, does not work on just that screen.

Comment: It's sad to realize that there are some people (who votes down with no reasonable comment) here dumb as Toshiba support who thinks this is not a problem but a "feature" of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple that you shutdown your computer completely, then take the power supply off completely. Wait one minute and restart your computer to windows screen, do again " F7 restart process" and everything will be okay.

Answer (score -1):

You've got some kind of fast boot enabled, If so, your USB ports are NOT powered until windows has loaded. To fix this, simply disable the fast boot options and there you go.

If that wont work, check your boot options and see if you can put your USBs to boot earlier (Priority lift)

Worked for me.

Comment: You might want to describe just *what* this fastboot is, why it causes the problem and *how* to disable it or use the "priority lift" option you mentioned. As it is you've given some good hints but you're just missing out on being a great answer.

Comment: I was using the notebook's own keyboard, but it is a good idea to try your suggestion with a USB keyboard.